# Can we set custom userid value to User_id column in request table in Azure logs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure-devops, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I need to set the *custom value* to the *User_id column* in the **request table** of Azure logs.
This is to collect the insights about the users who access and visits my web-application.

I've a working method that would send user_id to application insights as **customEvents** from my MVC application.
Yet, I would like to set the value in the request table itself.

I would appreciate your suggestions, if this can be done !.
Thank you !.

Comment: Would this help? https://www.azureblue.io/how-to-log-http-request-body-with-asp-net-core-application-insights/

Comment: @DA Thanks!, thinks this article kinda helped me in other ways. Though, I believe it doesn't align with my scenario.